# Laravel - How to display input value inside backticks?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple dates in my table, for example : (date1, date2, date3...).

I use `for` loop to create inputs with their own values.

I use Ajax to create inputs (this is not the essencial) :

```
for (var i = 1; i <= data[0].nb_jour; i++) {
  createDateInput += `<input type="date" value="{{$formation->date.`+i+`}}" name="date`+i+`">`;
```

With this simple way (html script), that's works :

```
<input type="date" value="{{$formation->date1}}" name="date1">
```

But I don't want to repeat lines like so :

```
 <input type="date" value="{{$formation->date1}}" name="date1">
 <input type="date" value="{{$formation->date2}}" name="date2">
 <input type="date" value="{{$formation->date3}}" name="date3">
    ...
```

Instead of `value="{{$formation->date1}}"`

I use in the `for` loop : `` ...value="{{$formation->date.`+i+`}}"... ``, But doesn't give the value.

**My question is : How to display / get the value inside backticks properly ?**

Comment: You're mixing server side script (php) and client side script (js). Server side script is executed before the server response, so your js loop will only happens afterward. you need to create the loop in php.

Comment: ah okey Thank you for the info !! I will try that